# Is there a Twitter API to retrieve entire conversation

Tags: php, python, twitter

I was looking this [site](http://www.conweets.com/index) and liked this idea. I wonder whether there's a way to retrieve entire conversation against a tweet?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not provide an API endpoint that enables an entire conversation to be retrieved. You would have to use the Twitter search API to find references to the original Tweet as replies, and build the conversation threads yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, you mean I search two handles and find some *way* to figure out whether it's part of same conversation?